# JPDA Query and Play - User and Roles (JOIN)

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, jpql

I have two play JPA Objects User.java & UserRole.Java

```
 public User(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Status status, List<UserRole> roles){
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.status = status; 
        this.roles = roles;
    }
```

UserRole

```
public UserRole(User user,RoleType roleType, Status status) {
         this.user = user;
         this.roleType = roleType;
         this.status = status;
     }
```

UserRoles are mapped to a user by

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public List<UserRole> roles;
```

I was hoping to write a play JPQL query that would return all users with a specified role- Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have designed your model like that, with two table `User.java` & `UserRole.java`), it would be little complicated to accomplish your goal.

If your `User.java` Model extends `play.db.jpa.Model` class, the solution might be like below:

```
// by using nested query to find all user that has admin role
List<User> userList = User.find(
    "id IN (SELECT user FROM models.UserRole WHERE roleType = ?)", 
    RoleType.ADMIN
).fetch();
```

The above expression is the same as SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM user_role WHERE role_type = 'ADMIN'
);
```